# Assigning a value to a Sub generates Compile Error: Argument Not optional

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to run this macro I get a msg saying

> Compile Error: Argument Not optional

and it highlights the pressureDrop in the last equation.

```
Public Sub pressureDrop(p As Double, L As Double, _
                        D As Double, u As Double, _
                        e As Double, w As Double)

    Dim A As Double, B As Double, f As Double, k As Double
    Dim Re As Double, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range

    Re = p * D * u / w

    With WorksheetFunction

        A = (2.457) * .Ln(1 / (7 / Re) ^ 0.9 + (0.27 * e / D))
        B = (37530 / Re) ^ 16
        f = 2 * ((8 / Re) ^ 12 + 1 / (A + B) ^ (3 / 2)) ^ (1 / 12)

        Set Rng1 = Range("D2:D29")
        Set Rng2 = Range("E2:E29")
        k = .SumProduct(Rng1, Rng2)

    End With

    pressureDrop = p * ((4 * f * (L / D) + k) * (u ^ 2) / 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: You are trying to write a `Function`, not a `Sub`.  Change the declaration to `Public Function pressureDrop(...`

Comment: The main problem is that your code is trying to assign a return value to a Sub(). The only way to return values is from a Function(). But if you provide more context the community will be able to guide you better

Answer (score 0):

You can also Dim another variable and assign the final value to it instead of assigning it to pressuredrop

```
Dim dAnswer as Double
dAnswer = p * ((4 * f * (L / D) + k) * (u ^ 2) / 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to a function:

```
Public Function pressureDrop(...)
    ...

    pressureDrop = p * ((4 * f * (L / D) + k) * (u ^ 2) / 2)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Public Sub pressureDrop(p As Double, L As Double, _
                    D As Double, u As Double, _
                    e As Double, w As Double)
```

With

```
Public Function pressureDrop(p As Double, L As Double, _
                    D As Double, u As Double, _
                    e As Double, w As Double) as Double
```